# In socketscan is there any plugin which is browser supported

Tags: barcode-scanner, socketscan, socketmobile

In socketscan is there any plugin which is browser supported. I am developing web application in which there is barcode scanning, I am looking forward to socketscan.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there are only two options for getting decoded data in the browser: HID Mode or a scanner enabled browser app

### HID mode

If the scanner is in HID mode, you can scan into any app (including the browser)

**Pros**

- Works on all platforms

**Cons***

- Input field must be selected
- Input field must be enabled - user editable
- App cannot manipulate data

* You can write or use a javascript library that captures rapid input - most likely from a scanner - to get around these. However, HID mode still isn't recommended, because it is less reliable.

### ScanBox - iOS only

[Free on iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scanbox/id973197674?mt=8). Is a basic browser that uses SocketScan to send decoded data to either the first, visible `<input>` or the element with a specific id.

**Pros**

- Reliable, because it uses ScanAPI (SocketScan)
- Data is always delivered to the same input, regardless of which element has the focus
- Input can be disabled - not user editable

**Cons**

- App cannot manipulate data

### 3rd Party app

For example, the iOS app [Enterprise Browser for Socket Mobile](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/enterprise-browser-for-socket/id1010802782?mt=8) by Dryrain Technologies.

**Pros**

- More control over where data is routed
- Javascript API

**Caveats**

- You must purchase a license to use all the features